# Collapsable div - remove picture keep heading

Tags: javascript, html, css

Simple thing probably, but it seems especially for my version I did not find any solution.

This simple div shows a big picture, heading and long text. I want that if you click onto the picture, it will collapes/remove all of that on the site so it will have more space. BUT - the Heading should still stay (probably in a smaller format).

I tried to make it collapseable with javascript, but I can't really get it to work that the heading stays there even though the rest get's removed. Because the heading needs to stay, so with another click onto the heading you can bring it back if needed.

I'd like to do that with CSS/Javascript and without Angular.JS or similiar, any of you got a solution?

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png"></img><br>
    <h3>HEADING</h3><br>
    <blockquote class="form-text text-muted">Long Text in here</blockquote> 
</div>
```

Comment: are you able to change in html ?

Comment: What did you already try? As you stated `I tried to make it collapseable with javascript`, any code? That way you may be able to learn better from the solution.

Comment: Show me what you tried in javascript. I will help you :) `I tried to make it collapseable with javascript`

Comment: you can checkout my answer. I think it does what you need. if not please specify further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put click event to elements you want to click and a function to execute after clicking. I've added id property to image header to be able to fetch it with javascript.

```html
<div id="header">
    <img id="imageInHeader" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" onclick="hideMe()"></img><br>
    <h3 onclick="showMe()">HEADING</h3><br>
    <blockquote class="form-text text-muted">Long Text in here</blockquote> 
</div>

<script>
function hideMe() {
  document.getElementById('imageInHeader').style.display = 'none';  // removes the element from the layout
  // document.getElementById('imageInHeader').style.visibility = 'hidden'  // hides the element, doesn't affect layout
}

function showMe() {
  document.getElementById('imageInHeader').style.display = 'block';
  // document.getElementById('imageInHeader').style.visibility = 'visible'
}
  
</script>
```

Comment: i don't know why the downvote since this example is working.

Comment: This is perfect! Works like a charm, thank you! The only weird thing is, when using the show fuction onclick of HEADING, it does create a bit more space between the heading and the logo above. Also in the snippet, doesnt it?

Comment: I don't think so. I've checked in chrome dev tools and it seems the same. whic browser are you using?

Comment: Happens to me in Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) and on IE (emulated 11, as we use this for intra). Ill message you.

Answer (score 0):

check this out
 in case your are not able to make changes in your html

```js
$('#image').click(function() {
  $("#header #image").css("display", "none");
  $("#header .text-muted").css("display", "none");
  
});
$('#header h3').click(function() {
  if($("#header #image").css("display") == "none"){
    $("#header #image").css("display", "block")
  }
  if($("#header .text-muted").css("display") == "none"){
    $("#header .text-muted").css("display", "block")
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <img id="image" src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"></img><br>
    <h3>HEADING</h3><br>
    <blockquote class="form-text text-muted">Long Text in here</blockquote> 
</div>
```

hope this solve your problem
thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="header" id="collapseThisDiv">
   <img src="img/logo.png"></img><br>
   <h3>HEADING</h3>
   <blockquote class="form-text text-muted">Long Text in here</blockquote>
</div>
<div id="header" id="expandThisDiv">
    <img src="img/logo.png"></img><br>
    <h3>HEADING</h3>
</div>
```

On 'image' click, Hide the above div and show the lower div and vice versa... This way it won't appear that heading is collapsed at any time.